# javascript function called on loop while waiting for ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two .asp scripts -  1st copies the contents of sys.tables and sys.views to another table in SQL.  The 2nd script calculates the percentage complete

(count(*) from newtable / (count(*) from sys.tables + count(*) from sys.views)) * 100

I have a function to call the first script.

```
function importTablesAndViews()
{
    xmlhttpImportTablesAndViews=GetXmlHttpObject();

    if (xmlhttpImportTablesAndViews==null)
    {
      alert ("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
      return;
    }
    url="importtablesandviews.asp";
    url=url+"?sid="+Math.random();

    xmlhttpImportTablesAndViews.onreadystatechange=function(){if (xmlhttpImportTablesAndViews.readyState==4){
        var aspResponse = xmlhttpImportTablesAndViews.responseText; 
    alert(aspResponse); }}
    xmlhttpImportTablesAndViews.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttpImportTablesAndViews.send(null);
}
```

I have another function to call the progress script

```
function refreshImportProgress()
{
    //alert('Refresh...');
    xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress=GetXmlHttpObject();

    if (xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress==null)
    {
      alert ("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
      return;
    }
    url="importtablesandviewsprogress.asp";
    url=url+"?sid="+Math.random();

    xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress.onreadystatechange=function(){if (xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress.readyState==4){
        var aspResponse = xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress.responseText; document.getElementById('progressDiv').innerHTML = aspResponse; }}
    xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress.send(null);
}
```

What I want to be able to do is call the refreshImportProgress() function on a 3 second interval from within the importTablesAndViews() function.

Is this possible?  I have tried googling simultaneous ajax requests but so far have not had much luck.

Answer (score 0):

Start a timer (`setTimeout`) with `refreshImportProgress` in the `onreadystatechange` handler of `xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress` (as long as the progress is below 100%):

```
function refreshImportProgress() {
    // ...

    xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById('progressDiv').innerHTML = xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress.responseText;

            var progress = parseInt(xmlhttpRefreshImportProgress.responseText, 10);
                        // ↑ this assumes the value of responseText is a integer only or a integer with a percentage symbol (44%)

            if (progress < 100) {
                setTimeout(refreshImportProgress, 3000);
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

And in `importTablesAndViews()` just call `refreshImportProgress` after sending the request:

```
function importTablesAndViews() {
    // ...
    xmlhttpImportTablesAndViews.send(null);

    refreshImportProgress();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I have misunderstood the question.
But I'm not sure if anything to do with Ajax on a 3 second timer is the best way.  If you get a really slow browser for example you cannot guarantee the changes from your first method to have been completed in time.  Also a 3 second wait for fast browsers is likely unnecessary.

If you must do this then just call setTimeout() 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

It seems more likely you should implement a promise that is called whenever your issues that take time are resolved. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Or even an event listener.  Heres a list.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Shouldn't ever really need to use timeout unless you just want to delay asynch things until the next tick.